# Redundant answers of reified predicate variant of append/3

Tags: list, prolog, reification, logical-purity

I wanted to offer a logically pure solution to some 
[other recent problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325785/how-can-i-delete-every-occurrence-of-a-sublist-from-a-list-in-prolog) in this forum.

As a start, I implemented a reified variant of `append/3` and named it `appendR/4`. It is based on the predicates `if_/3` and `(=)/3` implemented by @false in [Prolog union for A U B U C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c):

```
appendR([],Ys,Zs,T) :- 
    =(Ys,Zs,T).
appendR([X|Xs],Ys,ZZs,T) :-
    if_([X|Zs] = ZZs, appendR(Xs,Ys,Zs,T), T = false).
```

The implementation basically works, as shown by the following queries:

```
?- appendR([1,2],Ys,[2,3,4],T).
T = false ? ;
no

?- appendR([1,2],[3,4],Xs, T).
T = true,  Xs = [1,2,3,4],                       ? ;
T = false, Xs = [1,2|_A],  prolog:dif([3,4],_A)  ? ;
T = false, Xs = [1|_A],    prolog:dif([2|_B],_A) ? ;
T = false,                 prolog:dif([1|_A],Xs) ? ;
no
```

So far, so good... Here comes the tricky part:

```
?- appendR([1,2],Ys,[1,2,3,4],T).
T = true,  Ys = [3,4]                   ? ;
T = false, prolog:dif(Ys,[3,4])         ? ;
T = false, prolog:dif([2|_A],[2,3,4])   ? ;
T = false, prolog:dif([1|_A],[1,2,3,4]) ? ;
no
```

I want to get the first two answers, but not the last two. Help, please!

Comment: I still do not know a good answer, but for the time being the fact `append([], Xs, Xs).` is a deliberate generalization. I am not sure that it makes sense to reify the generalization itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also coded an alternative variant `appendRR/4`:

```
appendRR([],Ys,Zs, T) :- 
    =(Ys,Zs,T).
appendRR([_|_],_,[], false).
appendRR([X|Xs],Ys,[Z|Zs], T) :-
    if_(X=Z, appendRR(Xs,Ys,Zs,T), T = false).
```

It does not give redundant answers:

```
?- appendRR([1,2],Ys,[1,2,3,4],T).
T = true,  Ys = [3,4]           ? ;
T = false, prolog:dif(Ys,[3,4]) ? ;
no
```

However, the goal `appendRR([1,2],_,foo,T)` fails. I'd prefer getting the answer `T = false`. This *is* bugging me somewhat.

I still feel it can be tolerated if the caller of `appendRR` can guarantee that non-list terms will never be used as the 3rd argument of `appendRR/4`.

Answer (score 1):

Next try: `append_t/4`. It should combine the "best" of [`appendR/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29444527/4609915) and [`appendRR/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29492940/4609915).

First, we define the reified non-empty-list testing predicate `cons_t/2`:

```
cons_t(V,T) :- 
   (  nonvar(V)                         % we can decide right now!
   -> (  V = [_|_]
      -> T = true
      ;  T = false
      )
   ;  V = [_|_],          T = true      % go nondet!
   ;  freeze(V,V\=[_|_]), T = false
   ).
```

Building on `cons_t/2`, `(=)/3`, and `if_/3` we define `append_t/4` like so:

```
append_t([],Bs,Cs,T) :-
   =(Bs,Cs,T).
append_t([A|As],Bs,Cs0,T) :-
   if_(cons_t(Cs0),
       (Cs0=[C|Cs], if_(A=C, append_t(As,Bs,Cs,T), T=false)),
       T=false).
```

---

Let's queries and compare the answers we get! Bad results are highlighted (written in **bold-face**).

1. ```
   ?- appendR([1,2],[3,4],Cs,T).
     T = true ,     Cs=[1,2,3,4]
   ; T = false,     Cs=[1,2|_X] , dif(_X,[3,4])
   ; T = false,     Cs=[1|_X]   , dif(_X,[2|_])
   ; T = false, dif(Cs,[1|_]).

   ?- appendRR([1,2],[3,4],Cs,T).
     T = false, Cs = []
   ; T = false, Cs = [1]
   ; T = true , Cs = [1,2,3,4]
   ; T = false, Cs = [1,2|_X] , dif(_X,[3,4])
   ; T = false, Cs = [1,_X|_] , dif(_X,2)
   ; T = false, Cs = [_X|_]   , dif(_X,1).

   ?- append_t([1,2],[3,4],Cs,T).
     T = true , Cs = [1,2,3,4]
   ; T = false, Cs = [1,2|_X] , dif(_X,[3,4])
   ; T = false, Cs = [1,_X|_] , dif(_X,2)
   ; T = false, Cs = [1|_X]   , freeze(_X,_X\=[_|_])
   ; T = false, Cs = [_X|_]   , dif(_X,1)
   ; T = false, freeze(Cs,Cs\=[_|_]).
   ```
2. ```
   ?- appendR([1,2],Bs,[1,2,3,4],T).
     T = true ,     Bs=[3,4]
   ; T = false, dif(Bs,[3,4])
   ; T = false
   ; T = false.

   ?- appendRR([1,2],Bs,[1,2,3,4],T).
     T = true ,     Bs=[3,4]
   ; T = false, dif(Bs,[3,4]).

   ?- append_t([1,2],Bs,[1,2,3,4],T).
     T = true ,     Bs=[3,4]
   ; T = false, dif(Bs,[3,4]).
   ```
3. ```
   ?- appendR([1,2],_,[2,3,4],T).
   T = false.

   ?- appendRR([1,2],_,[2,3,4],T).
   T = false.

   ?- append_t([1,2],_,[2,3,4],T).
   T = false.
   ```
4. ```
   ?- appendR([1,2],_,non_list,T).
   T = false.

   ?- appendRR([1,2],_,non_list,T).
   false.

   ?- append_t([1,2],_,non_list,T).
   T = false.
   ```

**Summary:** `appendR/4` and `appendRR/4` fail with some test cases, `append_t/4` does not.

Comment: Cases with `non_list` are neither true nor false: They are out of scope! Think of `append_t(non_list, _, _, T)` where all your versions fail. Same applies for the other arguments.

Comment: Right! OTOH the common definition of `append/3` is asymmetric wrt. argument generalization, type testing, indexing, and (possibly) more.

Comment: The generalization in `append/3`'s fact is here to facilitate a more efficient execution. Nothing else.