# gathering two files to another file

Tags: io, prolog

i have two files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, I would like collected them in `file3.txt` after checking lines of two files.

example :

**file1.txt**

```
line 1    T
line 2    F
line 3    T
line 4    T
line 5    F
line 6    F
```

**file2.txt**

```
line 1    T
line 2    T
line 3    F
line 4    T
line 5    F
line 6    T
```

**file3.txt**

```
    file1 
    ********************
    number of line  = 6
    number of true  = 3
    number of false = 3
    ********************
    line 1    T
    line 3    T
    line 4    T

    file2
    ********************
    number of line  = 6
    number of true  = 4
    number of false = 2
    ********************
    line 1    T
    line 2    T
    line 4    T
    line 6    T
```

For each file, the resulting file should contain a header showing the number of lines, the number of lines that were true (`T`) and the number of lines that were false (`F`). Next **only the lines that were true** are printed.

some help ?

Comment: `F` or `T` will always be the last character on the line?

Comment: yes, but that's not important to keep the white spaces

Comment: Are the lines themselves "T", "F", etc, or are they "line 1 T", "line 2 F", etc?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem,Boris what I do so far is implementing a predicate `file_to_list (File, List)`
the result: List = ['line-1-T', 'line-2-F, ...]

Comment: @AnsPiter: do you want `file3` to be indented? Or is this a typo?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  this is a typo

Comment: @AnsPiter: and another question: do you want to print `file1` or `file1.txt` in the resulting file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows. We first define a predicate `merge/2` with the first item a list of filenames that must be read (here `[file1.txt,file2.txt]`), and the second parameter the name of the file to which you wish to write (here `file3.txt`). Now we define `merge/2` as:

```
merge(Inp,Outp) :-
    open(Outp,write,Outs),
    mergeS(Inp,Outs).
```

So we open a file with the name `Outp` and the get the corresponding stream `Outs`, we then call `mergeS/2`.

There are two cases for `mergeS/2`:

- all input files have been processed, so we can stop processing and close the stream:

  ```
  mergeS([],OutS) :-
      close(OutS).
  ```
- there is still at least one file we need to process:

  ```
  mergeS([H|T],OutS) :-
      open(H,read,InS),
      atom_chars(FileN,H),
      process(FileN,InS,OutS),
      close(InS),
      mergeS(T,OutS).
  ```

  The core of this predicate is evidently `process/3`, but in order to make things more convenient. We do the file handling already in `mergeS`.

Next our **`process/3`** predicate reads:

```
process(Header,InS,OutS) :-
    get_lines(InS,Lin,NL,NT,NF),
    write(OutS,Header),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'********************'),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'number of line  = '),write(OutS,NL),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'number of true  = '),write(OutS,NT),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'number of false = '),write(OutS,NF),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'********************'),nl(OutS),
    print_lines(OutS,Lin),
    nl(OutS).
```

We first gather the content of the file with `get_lines/5`. This predicate will simultaneously calculate statistics like the number of lines, the number of trues and the number of false. Next we use a number of `write/2` and `nl/1` statements to write statistics to the output file and then use a predicate `print_lines/2` that will write the content of the file to `file3.txt`:

**`get_lines` and `get_line`**

`get_lines/5` uses three accumulators to calculate statistics. This is done by initializing three *accumulators* and then make a call to `get_lines/8`:

```
get_lines(Ins,Lin,NL,NT,NF) :-
    get_lines(Ins,Lin,0,0,0,NL,NT,NF).
```

`get_lines/8` is a recursive function that processes one line at a time, determines whether the line is `T` or `F`, updates the accumulators, and will parse the next line. It is however possible that we are given an empty file. In order to make our approach more robust we thus write:

```
get_lines(InS,[],NL,NT,NF,NL,NT,NF) :-
    at_end_of_stream(InS),
    !.
```

and the recursive case:

```
get_lines(InS,[H|T],NL0,NT0,NF0,NL,NT,NF) :-
    get_line(InS,HCs),
    inspect(HCs,NL0,NT0,NF0,NL1,NT1,NF1),
    atom_chars(H,HCs),
    get_lines(InS,T,NL1,NT1,NF1,NL,NT,NF).
```

`get_line/2` simply reads the next line of the file, and returns a stream of characters. It terminates at `'\n'` (inclusive, but not in the result).

```
get_line(InS,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(InS),
    !.
get_line(InS,[H|T]) :-
    get_char(InS,H),
    H \= '\n',
    !,
    get_line(InS,T).
get_line(_,[]).
```

**`inspect/7`**

Now we still have to inspect our line with `inspect/7`. We again use three accumulators (as you could already guess based on the implementation of `get_lines/8`). First we fetch the last character of the line. If no such character exists, the statistics won't change (it could be possible somewhere an empty line is introduced). Otherwise we obtain the last character with `last/2` and inspect it with `inspect_last/7`:

```
inspect(L,NL0,NT0,NF0,NL,NT,NF) :-
    last(L,LL),
    !,
    NL is NL0+1,
    inspect_last(LL,NT0,NF0,NT,NF).
inspect(_,NL0,NT,NF,NL1,NT,NF) :-
    !,
    NL1 is NL0+1.
```

`inspect_last` determines whether the last character is a `T`, `F` or something else, and updates the accumulators accordingly:

```
inspect_last('T',NT0,NF,NT1,NF) :-
    !,
    NT1 is NT0+1.
inspect_last('F',NT,NF0,NT,NF1) :-
    !,
    NF1 is NF0+1.
inspect_last(_,NT,NF,NT,NF).
```

**`print_lines/2`**:

finally we still need to print our file to the output. This is done using `print_lines/2` which is rather straightforward:

```
print_lines(_,[]) :-
    !.
print_lines(OutS,[H|T]) :-
    write(OutS,H),
    nl(OutS),
    print_lines(OutS,T).
```

## Full code

The full code:

```
merge(Inp,Outp) :-
    open(Outp,write,Outs),
    mergeS(Inp,Outs).

mergeS([],OutS) :-
    close(OutS).

mergeS([H|T],OutS) :-
    open(H,read,InS),
    atom_chars(FileN,H),
    process(FileN,InS,OutS),
    close(InS),
    mergeS(T,OutS).

process(Header,InS,OutS) :-
    get_lines(InS,Lin,NL,NT,NF),
    write(OutS,Header),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'********************'),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'number of line  = '),write(OutS,NL),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'number of true  = '),write(OutS,NT),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'number of false = '),write(OutS,NF),nl(OutS),
    write(OutS,'********************'),nl(OutS),
    print_lines(OutS,Lin),
    nl(OutS).

get_lines(Ins,Lin,NL,NT,NF) :-
    get_lines(Ins,Lin,0,0,0,NL,NT,NF).

get_lines(InS,[],NL,NT,NF,NL,NT,NF) :-
    at_end_of_stream(InS),
    !.
get_lines(InS,[H|T],NL0,NT0,NF0,NL,NT,NF) :-
    get_line(InS,HCs),
    inspect(HCs,NL0,NT0,NF0,NL1,NT1,NF1),
    atom_chars(H,HCs),
    get_lines(InS,T,NL1,NT1,NF1,NL,NT,NF).

get_line(InS,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(InS),
    !.
get_line(InS,[H|T]) :-
    get_char(InS,H),
    H \= '\n',
    !,
    get_line(InS,T).
get_line(_,[]).

inspect(L,NL0,NT0,NF0,NL,NT,NF) :-
    last(L,LL),
    !,
    NL is NL0+1,
    inspect_last(LL,NT0,NF0,NT,NF).
inspect(_,NL0,NT,NF,NL1,NT,NF) :-
    !,
    NL1 is NL0+1.

inspect_last('T',NT0,NF,NT1,NF) :-
    !,
    NT1 is NT0+1.
inspect_last('F',NT,NF0,NT,NF1) :-
    !,
    NF1 is NF0+1.
inspect_last(_,NT,NF,NT,NF).

print_lines(_,[]) :-
    !.
print_lines(OutS,[H|T]) :-
    write(OutS,H),
    nl(OutS),
    print_lines(OutS,T).
```

If one now queries:

```
?- merge(["file1.txt","file2.txt"],"file3.txt").
true.
```

a file named `file3.txt` is constructed with content:

```
file1.txt
********************
number of line  = 6
number of true  = 3
number of false = 3
********************
line 1    T
line 2    F
line 3    T
line 4    T
line 5    F
line 6    F

file2.txt
********************
number of line  = 6
number of true  = 4
number of false = 2
********************
line 1    T
line 2    T
line 3    F
line 4    T
line 5    F
line 6    T
```

Which is more or less what you want. Please comment if further errors occur.

**EDIT**

Somehow I didn't get you wanted to filter the lines and only show the ones that are true (`T`). You can do so by simply modifying `get_lines/7`:

```
get_lines(InS,[],NL,NT,NF,NL,NT,NF) :-
    at_end_of_stream(InS),
    !.
get_lines(InS,Res,NL0,NT0,NF0,NL,NT,NF) :-
    get_line(InS,HCs),
    inspect(HCs,NL0,NT0,NF0,NL1,NT1,NF1),
    atom_chars(H,HCs),
    ( NT1 > NT0
    -> Res =[H|T]
    ; Res = T
    ),
    get_lines(InS,T,NL1,NT1,NF1,NL,NT,NF).
```

(added boldface where the content changed)

This is not the most elegant way to do it, but it is probably the shortest fix.

Now the file on my machine shows:

```
file1.txt
********************
number of line  = 6
number of true  = 3
number of false = 3
********************
line 1    T
line 3    T
line 4    T

file2.txt
********************
number of line  = 6
number of true  = 4
number of false = 2
********************
line 1    T
line 2    T
line 4    T
line 6    T
```

Comment: i have this prob :  `merge(['file1','file2'],'file3').
! Permission error: cannot open file 'c:/users/coper/file3'
! not writeable
! goal:  open(file3,write,_201)`

Comment: @AnsPiter: well it speaks for itself: somehow your operating system blocks access to that directory. I don't  know how to solve this for Windows: already Linux-only for 7 years.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem thnx anyway, i will install linux

Comment: @AnsPiter: does the file already exists? Perhaps your operating system prevents the file from being overwritten...

Comment: @WWillem Van Onsem  file.txt or file is it the same in prolog(SPIDER-plugin) ?

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem: i solve the problem of **Permission**  in predicate mergeS  `%atom_chars(FileN,H),     % deleted
process(H,InS,OutS),   % FileN replaced  by H `   then create files.txt outside Sicstus-prolog   /... /src/files.txt  and when i tape query i change "_" by '_' `| ?- merge(['file1.txt','file2.txt'],'file.txt').
yes 
`

Comment: the problem now is how i can delete the false lines from file3.txt

Comment: @AnsPiter: ah, I missed that in your problem statement. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem: did you learn prolog  yourself or at university ?

Comment: @AnsPiter: at university. But I developed some passion for it since it is an elegant way to solve reasoning problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough sketch to get you started using [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) and [`library(pio)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pio).

We take `lines//1`, as defined my @mat in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805709/4609915) to the related question "[Read a file line by line in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4805601/4609915)". Using [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and [`prefix_of_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29449765/4609915) we then write:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes      , codes),
   set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).
true.

?- phrase_from_file(lines(_Ls), 'file1.txt'),
   maplist(reverse, _Ls, _Rs),
   tpartition(prefix_of_t("T"), _Rs, _Ts0, _Fs),
   maplist(reverse, _Ts0, _Ts),
   forall(member(X,_Ts), format('~s~n',[X])).
line 1    T
line 3    T
line 4    T
true.
```

Comment: thnx it's work with PDT-eclipse(SWI) but so far, i must to use SICStus-prolog

Comment: SWI is it better than SICStus ?

Comment: @AnsPiter. Both got strong and weak points, so my answer is twofold: (1) It depends. (2) YMMV! :)

Comment: I think that this depends largely on pith of libraries, so RMV.